# How to uninstall automatically while installing new version in msi file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-installer

I have made a msi project for my software in VS2015. I have made a.Net based desktop application. My requirement is that I would like to handle 2 cases :--

1- If our software is installed already, and user try to install it, it should automatically un-install existing software and delete database file (created by my application).

2- If installed version is lower then it should only uninstall application and leave my database file as it is.

Now in my setup project I have added Custom actions for install and un-install where I have given path of my dll and set Installer Class property to true. In this dll I have made a class inherited from System.Configuration.Install.Installer and handle Install , beforeInstall, uninstall like below :--

```
    public partial class SetupManager : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
    {
        public SetupManager()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BeforeInstall += SetupManager_BeforeInstall;
            //this.Committed += new InstallEventHandler(DarkMailInstaller_Committed);
        }

        private void SetupManager_BeforeInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("In Install event");
        }
}
```

Now in un-install, I delete DB. it is working fine if I am un-installing from control panel and it removes my DB file as well.

But if I want to upgrade my product, before getting hit in my override function Like install or BeforeInstall it shows error "Another Version of this product is already installed. Installation of this version can not be continue. To configure or remove the existing version of product, use add/remove program of control panel".

Now I have searched on internet and it seems if I update my package code or product version, it should be able to install over it. Now I have following issues :--

1- In VS 2015, I dont have any property in setup project where I can set product version or package code ?

2- I have tried to edit it using Orca but even then if I try to install edited MSI file (with updated version number, package code and product code), I am facing same error.

3- I dont know why this this error is coming before executing Before-install event ?

4- I have found "RemoveExistingProducts" would be helpful in this case. But I can not find this property / action in VS2015. Where can I find it ?

Can some body please help me to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Visual Studio setup project it's the RemovePreviousVersions property of the setup project, in with the other properties like Manufacturer, Version etc.

1. Increment the setup version's project version, accept the changes.
2. Set RemovePreviousVersions to true.
3. The UpgradeCode needs to be the same, so don't change it.
4. Increment the file versions of the binaries you need to be updated.

If you select the setup project in solution explorer and do F4 you should see the relevant properties.

Don't worry about PackageCode because Visual Studio creates a new one with every build, as it should.

Visual Studio custom actions all run after the files have been installed (despite the "before" name), so there's nothing you can do to influence the course of the installation. In any case you don't need them.

What you get is an MSI that will install as a fresh install to new customers. It will also upgrade an older product as it installs, and the Windows Installer overwrite rules mean that a data file updated by the application will not be replaced.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370531(v=vs.85).aspx

The generated MSI will have a RemoveExistingProducts sequenced towards the end of the install. Basically you don't need to worry about the internals of PackageCodes and so on because Visual Studio hides them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works for me. I don't have enough credentials but definitely it is +1 for me.